# if delete first section - app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

if i delete last cell in my sections, i need delete section

if i delete sections with end to begin - it's work perfect, but if i delete my first section - app crash

and my last sections - Add button

what happens ?

**my code**

```
- (void)deleteExerciseFromCustomTable:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [[_exercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [_previewTable beginUpdates];
    [_previewTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [_previewTable endUpdates];

    if ([[_exercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count] == 0) {
        [_group removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        [_previewTable beginUpdates];
        [_previewTable deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        [_previewTable endUpdates];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == [_group count]) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return [[_exercises objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [_group count] + 1;
}
```

Comment: You should either delete the row or the section, not both. But to be sure we need to see your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods.

Comment: Can you show your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`? Normally this means something is out of sync.

Comment: @ansible No need for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in this case. It's all about the counts.

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == [_group count]) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return [[_exercises objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }
}- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [_group count] + 1;
} group - is head in my base, and exercise - array with 2 or 3 array inside )

Comment: @alexwillrock Don't put the code in comments. Update your question with the code so it is readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem

```
 - (void)deleteExerciseFromCustomTable:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([[_exercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count] == 1) {
        [_group removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        [_exercises removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];        
        [_previewTable beginUpdates];
        [_previewTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        [_previewTable deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        [_previewTable endUpdates];

    }else{
        [[_exercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];            
        [_previewTable beginUpdates];
        [_previewTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];        
        [_previewTable endUpdates];        

    }
}
```